# MonteCarlo Value at Risk for a bonds portfolio

Tags: monte-carlo, value-at-risk, zero-coupon

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to calculate MC VaR for a portfolio consisting entirely of bonds.
I already modeled the zero curve using Vasicek and Cox,Ingersoll & Ross models.
Next steps are:

- Valuate the portfolio at date 0.
- Simulate N zero curves.
- Revaluate the portfolio N times.
- Calculate P&L.

My question is: where do I fit a Cholesky Decomposition into all this and If I should implement it at all ?

Comment: Do you know the (serious) problems with using VaR to evaluate the risk for a bond portfolio and have you already looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Monte_Carlo_simulation ?

Comment: What kind of bonds? Treasuries, so you just need one yield curve? Multiple currencies? Corporates, so you need to consider credit spread?

Comment: Sounds good! But - as also alluded to by other commenters - only for interest rate risk and plain vanilla instruments such as (credit risk free) bonds! You do not need the Cholesky decomposition. This decomposition can be a handy tool for generating and analysing the distribution but is not required.

Comment: @kurtosis ,yes and I don't have a say in it.

Comment: @DimitriVulis, @g g the bonds are subject only to interest rate risk, besides that I only have the facial amount,coupon rate and maturity date

Comment: @Sizirr01 Sorry to hear that, but we've all been there. I'd use the Cholesky to create correlated points on the curve. If we're being a little cheeky, I would also make benchmark points on the curve a little more independent while nearby points are more dependent on those key points. For example, I'd be more likely to believe a big move in the 2Y dragging along 21M and 27M points than 21M organically moving a lot on its own. Also, big caveat: maybe also track which bonds are in the cheapest-to-deliver basket for T-note/bond futures since that can affect pricing. Good luck!

Comment: @kurtosis sorry, a likely problem with allowing every tenor to move on its own in MC is that you'll get many zigzaggy market scenarios that simply don't look feel realistic; and in particular the tail of P&L distribution, where the book would lose the most money, would be mostly such unrealistic scenarios. It may suffice for a school project but probably won't be acceptable in the real world. I once programmed what you descibe (historical correlations between tenors). It was not good enough. I ended up re-doing it using principal components, as outlined in my answer.

Comment: @DimitriVulis I did not suggest letting anything vary independently; that would be insane. As someone who trades the curve of Eurodollars, I know exactly how insane it would be. My suggestion was to realize that some benchmark tenors tend to lead more than follow. While PCA is fine, one can do much better.

Comment: @kurtosis I see what you mean, thanks

Comment: @kurtosis: What are those serious problems of using VaR for bond portfolios?

Comment: You can construct bond portfolios where VaR prefers concentration to diversification, increasing risk. Not surprising since VaR is not coherent, but it can be a bit shocking if you haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

You have a portfolio of credit-risk-free bonds all in the sam currency, so just one yield curve.

You are tasked with setting up a Monte Carlo simulation that would create many different scenarios of changes in your yield curves that "look consistent" with the last several years of history.

I suggest you use principal components. Get the historical time series of daily changes in yield. For simplicity, assume that you have the yields "generic" bonds with the same tenors every day. (Note that you could use these historical time series directly on your bond portfolio to get a "historical VaR" and skip the whole MC exercise.) We will assume that the changes in each yield are lognormally distributed. Run principal components analysis on each curve.

Each PC is a weighted sum of the instruments used to construct the yield curve. The weights (aka loadings) are chosen so the PCs are uncorrelated to each other and that each consecutive PC explains the maximum of the unexplained curve variance. Generally, there will be much fewer PCs than the number of instruments used to build the yield curve. Increasing the number of PCs increasins the portion of yield curve variance explained by the PCs. The first 3 PCs have clear geometric interpretation: the first one is "level" or "parallel shift" (the loadings have the same sign and are close to being equal); the second one is "slope" or "tilt" or "flatness / steepness" or "twist"  (the loadings change the sign once); the whird one is "curvature", "bow", or "butterfly" (the loadings change the sign twice); while the higher numbered PCs have less intuitive geometric interpretation ("double humps", the loadings change signs many times). Since you'll be looking at tail risk (VaR is typically 99%) you should not limit yourself to the first 3 PCs, but use at least 6.

Actually, for the sake of generality, let us not assume one currency. You could have bonds in USD, EUR (bunds), GBP (gilts), and other currencies.  Each currency has one yield curve with some historical principal components, and you also have FX rates. Assume that the changes in the currency exchange rates are normally distributed. So your $n \times n$ covariance matrix  $C$ will have on the diagonal the historical variance of the FX rates and PCs; and off the diagonal, their historical covariance. The matrix will be sparse, with lots of zero correlations between the PCs, but for generality's sake, let us allow non-zero correlations between the FX rates. Assume that $C$ is positive definite so you can use Choleski.

The reason why I suggest using PCs, rather than treating each tenor of the yield curve as a random variable and having each tenor in the covariance matrix is that the MC would generate yield curve perturbations that are very unrealistic (don't look like the history and can't happen in real life).

Now (self-plagiarizing my recent answer [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/56001/simulating-covariance-matrices-with-nonzero-correlation/56012#56012), which has a little more mathematical bckground) you can use Choleski decomposition to find the $n \times n$ matrix $H$ such that  $H \times H^T = C$. You generate $Z$ of $n$ normally distributed random numbers. Multiply $Y=HZ$. Each scenario $Y$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and covariance $C$. As I already mentioned, you could skip the MC and just use your historical time series instead of (or even in addition to) $Y$.

The next step is to price your bond portfolio given the market data now. You are given the notional amounts, the coupons, and the maturities. You generate the cash flows of each bond in your portfolio. It would be better if you were given additional indicative information for the bonds, such as the freuency of the coupons (annual? quarterly?) and the daycount convention (30/360? Actual/Actual?). Without it, you can assume that they're like U.S. treasuries. To calculate the market value of the bonds given the yields and the currency exchange rates now, you discount each cash flow using the given yield and add them up; and if the bond is in another currency, then you also multiply by the exchange rate.

To calculate your profit and loss (P&L) under each scenario in $Y$, you note that each scenario in $Y$ contains a change in the FX rates (it is clear how to add that to the rate now); and also the change in the PCs. You multiply the PC change by the loadings to get the impact on the generic instruments in your yield curve. You reprice your bond portfolio under the perturbed FX rates and yield curves and subtract the original value of the portfolio to get the P&L under this scenario.

If you have, for example, 10,000 scenarios in $Y$, and you want 99% VaR, then you pick the 100th worst P&L and call it VaR.

For analysis, it is often interesting to look at the scenarios in $Y$ that led to the worse losses; to consider whether they look realistic, should be hedged, etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to give such a thorough answer